# User profile 'Reputation' section answer's colour is wrong

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, bounties, accepted-answer

> [image: bounty award event represented with awfully not bluuuueee background, despite the fact it actually should be {blue}]

^^On [my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A?tab=topactivity), the box for this specific question is coloured green, which means my answer is accepted... but it isn't.

Is this a bug? If it is, I guess the system makes bounties (which I just received) act as being accepted?

Comment: No bug, just a weird choice of colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your answer is *awarded a bounty*, the reputation earned you and I (and everyone else) see on your profile page will be green!

The answer in question was recently given a 250 rep bounty plus 4 later upvotes. That totals to 290 rep and a green colored in square like the one you chose. No bug, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Remember, any rep earned ***by an awarded bounty or accept*** will be shown as the picture above, except with a varying rep amount. And yes, Shadow Wizard is right:

> No bug, just a weird choice of colors.